# Make clients wait until the rest of the clients write to server

Tags: c

I have a multithreading TCP server that waits for a number of predefined clients to write something to the server side and base of the requests, the server will write a message to all the clients based on their request. I'm stuck at the part when the clients that already sent a message must wait until all the clients have sent their respective message. How can I do this? I attempted to write 2 different thread functions, the first one calling the second one but not sure if this is the right way. Is there a way to make the clients wait until the server writes to all of them?

Comment: According to your description you do not need threading for this. Just read the clients messages sequentially, from client 1 to n, and then reply sequentially to all of them.

Comment: ok that really makes sense but what if the client that let's say received a negative answer wants to try one more time, do I just take care of the rest of the clients and then deal with them sequentially?

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing the details of your protocol. Do the successful clients disconnect?

Comment: Yes they do if the condition is met.

Comment: I suggest you just use message passing. Clients send message to internal message queue after they did their thing, and wait for message to "continue". Whatever launched the clients counts these messages, and then sends the "continue" messages when it is time.

Comment: I don't see the problem, so I assume I'm misunderstanding something.  If all of the clients are going to write a message, and the server is not going to respond to any client until it has received a message from all clients, then each client can just send its message and wait for a response from the server.